# Self-join of a subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql

I was wondering, is it possible to join the result of a query with itself, using PostgreSQL?

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: And here I come here, after 12 years of posting this question, and I find that the question and answer are really useful :)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can do so with WITH:

```
WITH subquery AS(
    SELECT * FROM TheTable
) 
SELECT *
FROM subquery q1
JOIN subquery q2 on ...
```

Or by creating a VIEW that contains the query, and joining on that:

```
SELECT *
FROM TheView v1
JOIN TheView v2 on ...
```

Or the brute force approach: type the subquery twice:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM TheTable
) sub1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM TheTable
) sub2 ON ...
```

Comment: PostgreSQL does not support WITH queries in the latest version, 8.3, according to http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/unsupported-features-sql-standard.html.

Comment: If you can upgrade to 8.4, currently in beta, WITH is finally there, see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-with.html

Comment: Since my subquery is somewhat complex, I'll try with a view first, then the "brute force" solution.. Eventually I'll switch to using WITH when pgsql 8.4 ships :) Many thanks to everyone!

Comment: Does the brute-force actually execute the sub-query twice or is it smart enough to reuse the results?

Comment: Helped me to solve my problem

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean, the result of a query on a table, to that same table. If so, then Yes, it's possible... e.g.

```
--Bit of a contrived example but...
SELECT * 
FROM Table
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 
          UserID, Max(Login) as LastLogin
    FROM
          Table
    WHERE 
          UserGroup = 'SomeGroup'
    GROUP BY
          UserID

) foo
ON Table.UserID = Foo.UserID AND Table.Login = Foo.LastLogin
```

Comment: Sorry, just noticed your "I'm using PostGres" comment. Not sure if the above is syntactically correct in postgres.

Comment: It's fine AFAICS (except maybe for the 'foo' vs 'Foo' case conflict;-).

Comment: @Eoin: Well I meant joining the _results_ of the queries, but thanks for your help all the same :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just alias the queries:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  *
        FROM   table
        ) t1
JOIN    (
        SELECT  *
        FROM   table
        ) t2
ON      t1.column < t2.other_column
```