# Nested SQL Queries with Self JOIN - How to filter rows OUT

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have an SQLite3 database with a table upon which I need to filter by several factors. Once such factor is to filter our rows based on the content of other rows within the same table.

From what I've researched, a self `JOIN` is going to be required, but I am not sure how I would do that to filter the table by several factors.

Here is a sample table of the data:

```
Name    Part #  Status  Amount
---------------------------------           
Item 1  12345   New     $100.00 
Item 2  12345   New     $15.00 
Item 3  35864   Old     $132.56 
Item 4  12345   Old     $15.00
```

What I need to do is find any `Item`s that have the same `Part #`, one of them has an "Old" `Status` and the `Amount` is the same.

So, first we would get all rows with `Part #` "12345," and then check if any of the rows have an "Old" status with a matching `Amount`. In this example, we would have `Item2` and `Item4` as a result.

What now would need to be done is to return the REST of the rows within the table, that have a "New" `Status`, essentially discarding those two items.

Desired Output:

```
Name    Part #  Status  Amount
---------------------------------           
Item 1  12345   New     $100.00
```

*Removed all "Old" status rows and any "New" that had a matching "Part #" and "Amount" with an "Old" status.* (I'm sorry, I know that's very confusing, hence my need for help).

I have looked into the following resources to try and figure this out on my own, but there are so many levels that I am getting confused.

- [Self-join of a subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907366/self-join-of-a-subquery)
- [ZenTut](http://www.zentut.com/sql-tutorial/sql-self-join/)
- [Compare rows and columns of same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32522604/compare-rows-and-columns-of-same-table)

The first two links dealt with comparing columns within the same table. The third one does seem to be a pretty similar question, but does not have a readable answer (for me, anyway).

I do Java development as well and it would be fairly simple to do this there, but I am hoping for a single SQL query (nested), if possible.

Comment: Can you provide a sample expected output to clarify what you are desiring to occur?

Comment: In your example would you want item 3? It has no "new" record but it does have an Old one.  You seem to indicate not with "Removed all "OLD" status rows and any new that matched..."  @p1erstef has a good response IMO  it's definitely the occam razor's answer :P

Comment: Put another way... think you want to see all the new parts which didn't have a matching price and part number for an old name.

Answer (score 3):

The "not exists" statment should do the trick :

```
select * from table t1
where t1.Status = 'New'
and not exists (select * from table t2
  where t2.Status = 'Old'
  and t2.Part = t1.Part
  and t2.Amount = t1.Amount);
```

Comment: Seems to be most efficient though select * could be select 1 or a column name. * seems like overkill in memory/performance; but then again, maybe the engines are smart enough to ignore the select since nothing is used from it.

Comment: @xQbert Databases indeed ignore columns in EXISTS; it checks for *rows*, not for column values. (That's why [this is the only place where `SELECT *` is actually a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql/9843/clean-code-in-sql/30300/select).)

Answer (score 0):

This is a T-SQL answer. Hope it is translatable. If you have a big data set for matches you might change the not in to !Exists.

```
select *
from table
where Name not in(
            select Name 
            from table t1
            join table t2 
              on t1.PartNumber = t2.PartNumber
                 AND t1.Status='New'
                 AND t2.Status='Old'
                 and t1.Amount=t2.Amount)
and Status = 'New'
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried to understand what you want best I could...

```
SELECT DISTINCT yt.PartNum, yt.Status, yt.Amount 
FROM YourTable yt
JOIN YourTable yt2 
  ON yt2.PartNum = yt.PartNum 
 AND yt2.Status = 'Old' 
 AND yt2.Amount != yt.Amount
WHERE yt.Status = 'New'
```

This gives everything with a new status that has an old status with a different price.

Comment: I think the amounts actually need to match (=, not !=) and your `join` would need to be a `left` join and where clause would need `yt2.partNum is null`.  you want where partnum of old matches partnum of new and prices match where you have a new part w/o an old matching.

Answer (score 0):

could be using an innner join a grouped  select for get status old and not only this

```
select * from 
my_table 
INNER JOIN (
    select 
        Part_#
        , Amount
        , count(distinct Status)
        , sum(case when Status = 'Old' then 1 else 0 )
    from my_table 
    group part_#,  Amount, 
    having count(distinct Status)>1
    and sum(case when Status = 'Old' then 1 else 0 ) > 0 
) t on.t.part_# = my_table.part_# 
    and status = 'new'
    and my_table.Amount <> t.Amount
```